# Add a new column with a default value while coping a CSV from S3 to A Postgresql RDS instance using aws_s3.table_import_from_s3

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I'm importing a CSV file from S3. The problem is I need to add a unique identifier as all the data will be stored in a common table in PostgreSQL and we need to know from which S3 bucket the data came from.

I don't want to parse through the data and insert as the CSV could contain thousands of row and that will considerably slow things down.

We have been creating a new temp table for every s3 import till now but we need to come up with a different solution using a common permanent table.

Comment: Why?  If you have solution that works, why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: Using temporary tables to stage data to be inserted into permanent tables is an effective approach. Views with `INSTEAD OF` triggers to supply the needed default values might also work, but would be more complicated to implement. Of the two approaches, using temporary staging tables seems more easily managed.

Comment: I agree with @jjanes, if a solution works, use it. Why is a different solution needed? What is inadequate about the current solution?

Comment: @JohnH the reason why temp table cant be used is a bit long winded and specific to our use case it has nothing to do with performance or complexity issues but its a no go.

I would appreciate it if you can explain the view with triggers approach a bit deeper?

Comment: A brief explanation as to why temporary tables are unacceptable could influence other recommendations. The original question should also include a sample of the imput and desired result. In this case a single line of CSV input and the expected resulting table row should be sufficient.

Please refer to the PostgreSQL documentation for an explanation of `INSTEAD OF` triggers. If you encounter difficulties implementing this approach, then revise your question with specific details. The original post is too vague and abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the fact that you can (optionally) name the columns of the table into which you're inserting.

Suppose you're loading data into a table called loaded_data with the following structure:

```
create table loaded_data (
 a text,
 b text,
 c text,
 source_bucket text);
```

And your data file holds the values for a, b, and c in a comma delimited file.

The following would load the columns a, b, and, c and leave source_bucket as null:

```
postgres=> SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'loaded_data',
   'a,b,c', 
   '(format csv)',
   :'s3_uri'
);
```

Follow this up with

```
update data_table
set source_bucket = 'name of the current bucket'
where source_file is null;
```

and you're good to go. Make sure this happens inside a transaction so you don't end up with a nasty race condition, of course.

Alternatively, you could use a default value for source_bucket, setting the value before each load. This would avoid a retroactive update statement.

```
ALTER TABLE loaded_data ALTER COLUMN source_bucket SET DEFAULT 'bucket2';

postgres=> SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'loaded_data',
   'a,b,c', 
   '(format csv)',
   :'s3_uri'
);
```

See here for more information and examples:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.FileFormats.CustomDelimiter

Comment: What happens if say between loading data into Postgres and updating the value of null another transaction comes in, loads the data and t1 performs the update on data of both t1 and t2?

Comment: That's what transactions are for.  Put a BEGIN; in before the first statement and COMMIT; after the second.  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html